# How to cast to a user defined type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have to create a table with some user defined types and insert data.

I tried this way.

1. create type type1 as (i int);
2. create function mycast(int) returns type1 as 'select $1;' language 'sql';
3. create cast (int as type1) with function mycast(int) as implicit;
4. create table table_type(t type1);
5. insert into table_type values(1::type1);

Now the values are getting inserted but wrapped in parenthesis, like this

```
select * from table_type;

  t  
--------
 (1)

(1 rows)
```

I believe there might be an error in my function. Can someone help. I wanted basically a function that returns the same output as my input (without any () ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The type you defined is a composite type containing one attribute of type int.  The text representation of a composite type is parentheses around the attribute list.  But judging from your cast function (which is broken, because it returns a scalar and not a composite type), this isn't what you want at all.  The best you could do is to define a domain like this:

```
create domain type1 as int;
```

Then you don't even need a cast.

Comment: +1 for being faster. For reference [`CREATE DOMAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html)

Comment: @Peter thanks,but I need to use create type itself. My requirement is to test the create type syntaxes and user defined types.

Comment: Then please write a question that describes what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Peter: I want to create a type, create a table using that type, and insert data into the table. thanks